# Conditional type using a function param's typeof

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
const getParams = (
  cb: number | ((...args: any[]) => any)
): typeof cb extends number ? [] : Parameters<typeof cb> => { // Type 'number' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
  return []
}
```

This function doesn't rally make any sens, but it's just a simple representation of my issue.

For some reason typescript doesn't take in count the `extends` condition. I'd like to know if there's a proper way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use functino overloading:

```js
const getParams: {
  (cb: number): [],
  <T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(cb: T): Parameters<typeof cb>
} = (
  cb: number | Function
): any => {
  return []
}
```

Comment: This seems to fix the type error, but unfortunately the return type is always `[]` even if a callback is given (e.g. `getParams((arg: string) => null) // return type = []`)

Comment: @AnatoleLucet I've edited my answer to have a hopefully working solution.

Comment: Ah! Didn't think about overloads. Thanks